# Problem translating simple Matlab function to Python: ifft results are different

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, scipy, fft

I am trying to translate to Python a Matlab function that calculates the Stockwell Transform for a time serie. The function ("stran") is taken from FileExchange: https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45848-stockwell-transform-s-transform

My test data can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/9Bd047ye
You can copy paste to a text file and call it say "z.dat"

My translation seems to be working correctly except at the line calling ifft (using numpy.fft of scipy.fftpack).

The results from the Matlab function is accurate and [looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ0Ou.png)
(Plot made with:

```
figure;
imagesc(abs(ST));
axis xy; 
xlabel("Time sample");
ylabel("Frequency");
title("S-transform result using stran.m")
```

*** NB: Make sure to give the data array in argument to stran.m as a *row* vector.)

Now here is my Python translation.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import fftpack, linalg
from numpy import matlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt("z.dat")
data = data[np.newaxis, :]

# Determine array dimensions
N = data.shape[1]
Nhalf = int(np.fix(N/2))
is_odd = 0 if Nhalf*2==N else 1

# Do fft
freqs = np.concatenate([np.arange(0, Nhalf+1), np.arange(-Nhalf+1-is_odd, 0)]) / N
freqs = freqs[np.newaxis,:]
fdata = fftpack.fft(data)

# Compute all frequency domain Gaussians in one matrix
invfreqs = np.divide(1, freqs[:,1:Nhalf+1]).T
W = 2 * np.pi * np.multiply(matlib.repmat(freqs,Nhalf,1) , matlib.repmat(invfreqs,1,N))
G = np.exp((- W**2) / 2) # Gaussian in frequency domain

# Compute the Toeplitz matrix with the shifted frequency-domain data
HW = linalg.toeplitz(fdata[:, 0:Nhalf+1].T, fdata)
print(HW.shape)

# Exclude the first row, corresponding to zero frequency
HW = HW[1:Nhalf+1, :]

# Compute Stockwell Transform
ST = fftpack.ifft(np.multiply(HW, G), axis=1)

# Add the zero frequency row
ST0 = np.mean(data, axis=1) * np.ones(shape=(1, N))
ST = np.vstack((ST0, ST))

# Plot result
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 5))
im = ax1.pcolor(np.abs(ST))
ax1.set_xlabel("Time sample")
ax1.set_ylabel("Frequency")
ax1.set_title("S-Transform using my Python translation")
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

And the result is
[not the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zkdb.png)
It looks as if there is some warping. But I can't figure out why does that happen. I thought perhaps it had to do with the array ordering in Matlab vs Python, but the ifft here only acts on one dimension. Running the ifft row by row still gives the different results.

What is wrong with my code ?